Generate matrix with diagonal fill pattern
Input Data:
data = [15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

Expected Output\need help with:
The output should look something like this:
[15]
[14, 13]
[12, 11, 10]
[9, 8, 7, 6]
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

Current solution:
end_value = 15
data =  list(range(1,end_value+1)[::-1])
iterations = round(end_value**0.5)+1
last_index = [0]+[i*(i+1)+1 for i in range(iterations)]
out = [data[last_index[i]:last_index[i+1]] for i in range(len(last_index)-1)]
for p in out: print(p)

Current Output:
[15]
[14, 13]
[12, 11, 10, 9]
[8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3]
[2, 1]


https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

@matszwecja The code isn't working as intended and that makes it off-topic on Code Review.

@pacmaninbw It did before the edit.

You can do it destructively like this:
data = [15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

e = 1

while data:
    print(data[:e])
    data = data[e:]
    e += 1

Output:
[15]
[14, 13]
[12, 11, 10]
[9, 8, 7, 6]
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

Or, non-destructive:
data = [15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
i = 0
j = 1

while i < len(data):
    print(data[i:i+j])
    i += j
    j += 1


You've got 2 issues with your code:
As far as I understand, last_index is supposed to calculate number of elements after which a new row should start: 0, 1, 3, 6 - but your code returns 0, 1, 3, 7 - hence the wrong number of elements in later rows.
The number of elements should follow the sum of arithmetic sequence of 1, 2, 3 etc., which would be n = (1+i)*i/2
last_index = [(i*(i+1)+1)//2 for i in range(iterations)]

Now, the 2nd issue is number of steps:
Actually calculating it would be possible, but quite problematic as we'd pretty much have to solve previous equation for i.
But we don't actually need to do that, as we can figure it out iteratively:
rem = end_value

iterations = 0
cnt = 0
while rem>0:
    iterations += 1
    rem -= cnt
    cnt += 1

Ad 1.
If we wanted to assign the mathematical formula for it, we'd have to solve our previous formula n = (1+i)*i/2 for i. After plugging it to WolframAlpha, we get the following two solutions:
i = 1/2 (sqrt(8 n + 1) - 1)
i = 1/2 (-sqrt(8 n + 1) - 1)

Since the 2nd one is always negative and we know our i can be only positive value, we can discard it and plug the other one into our code to calculate iterations, rounding up (for numbers that don't feat neatly into a rows) and adding one to offset the intervals we're dealing with.
iterations = ceil((sqrt(8 * end_value + 1) - 1)/2) + 1

last_index = [(i*(i+1)+1)//2 for i in range(iterations)]

out = [data[last_index[i]:last_index[i+1]] for i in range(len(last_index)-1)]

for p in out:
    print(p)


Thank you, I've noticed the issue with the last_index.

And thank you for the  number of steps, as I couldn't figure it out.

@Gооd_Mаn I've added a piece of code for calculating it mathematically, if you're curious.

I've never heard about WolframAlpha until today, as I can see it is very useful resource!

data = [15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
i, L = 1, len(data)
while i <= L:
    
    print(data[:i])
    L = L - len(data[:i])
    del data[:i]     
    
    i += 1
    
    '''Output:
    [15]
    [14, 13]
    [12, 11, 10]
    [9, 8, 7, 6]
    [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
    '''


Thank you for your answer, but it doesn't match the expected output.

The last row should be [5, 4, 3, 2, 1].

@Gооd_Mаn, Pl see my edited answer now.

Great, thank you. I've upvoted your answer and thank you for your time!
If you could upvote my question it would be much appreciated as well.
